# Lua: Obtaining number of quarters and day of quarter

Tags: date, datetime, lua

I'm new to Lua and I'm trying to learn how to manipulate date values in Lua.

I have a database which has a date_id in INTEGER value, where it starts from 1st January 2000 (i.e. 1st Jan 2000 = 0, 2nd Jan 2000 = 1, 3rd Jan 2000 = 2 and so on)

How I get the year of the date would be:

```
basedate = (os.time{year=2000, month=1, day=1})
lua_dremel_seconds = 86400  --seconds in a day

local function Year(date_id)
    local lua_date_id = tostring(date_id) * lua_dremel_seconds 
    return os.date("%Y", basedate + lua_date_id)
end
```

What I'm trying to figure out are 2 things:

1. How should I manipulate the function to accurately get the number of quarters of a date since 1st Jan 2000? (i.e. any date_id between 1st Jan 2000 - 31st March 2000 = 0, 1st Apr 2000 - 30th Jun 2000 = 1 and so on)
2. How should I manipulate the function to accurately get day of quarter? (i.e. 1st Jan 2000 = 1, 2nd Jan 2000 = 2, 1st Apr 2000 = 1, 2nd Apr 2000 = 2)

Is there somehow an easy way to get this arithmetically from basedate+ lua_date_id, or should I be thinking from a completely different train of thought?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you convert an integer to a string just to multiply it with an integer?

Comment: `local quarter = math.floor((month-1)/12*4)+1`  what stops you from doing those calculations yourself?

Comment: Thanks @Piglet, was quite new to this so was just copying from the tutorial that i've learnt from as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function decode_date_id(date_id)
   local tm = os.time{year=2000, month=1, day=1+date_id}
   local dt = os.date("*t", tm)
   local month_q = dt.month - (dt.month - 1)%3
   local tm_q = os.time{year=dt.year, month=month_q, day=1}
   local q = (month_q-1)/3+(dt.year-2000)*4  -- number of quarter
   local q_day = math.floor((tm - tm_q)/86400 + 1.5)       -- day of quarter
   return dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, q, q_day
end

print(decode_date_id(7825))  -->  2021   6   4   85   65
```

Comment: Would this be a problem if January 1st 2001 has a date_id value of 366?

Comment: Code updated.  What is the output for 366 on your system?

Comment: Ah never mind, my bad as I think I had a slight mistake on my end, I think I can work with your logic, thank you so much for your help! :)